# TypeError when importing createRoot from 'react-dom/client'

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, react-dom

I am fairly new to react and JavaScript but I want to implement a whiteboard with React in Wordpress.

The whiteboard is not the problem (yet) because I am stuck at the import.

I created a package using npm and installed @wordpress/scripts. My package.json looks like this:

```json
{
  "name": "abcde_test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "none",
  "main": "build/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "wp-scripts start",
    "build": "wp-scripts build"
  },
  "author": "bylxly",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@wordpress/scripts": "^26.15.0"
  }
}
```

I created a .php file so that the plugin is recognized:

```php
<?php
/**
 *
 * Plugin Name:  abcde_test
 * Description:  none
 * Version:      1.0.0
 *
 * Author:       Bylxly 
 * License:      CC BY-NC 4.0
 * License URI:  http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/4.0
 *
 * Text Domain:  test
 */

 // Exit if accessed directly
 if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; 
}

// Define Paths
define('INS_PLUGIN_URL', plugins_url('', __FILE__));

function enqueue_custom_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-script', INS_PLUGIN_URL . '/build/index.js' );
}
add_action('init', 'enqueue_custom_script');
```

I've also read that I need to create a webpack.config.js, so I did:

```js
const defaults = require('@wordpress/scripts/config/webpack.config');

module.exports = {
    ...defaults,
    externals: {
        react: 'React',
        'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
    },
};
```

Then I created at src/index.js:
`import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';`

When I execute `npm start` everything builds and is normal, but when I look at the console of my browser in Wordpress, I see following:

```
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'm.__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED')
    ./node_modules/react-dom/client.js (index.js:15)
    __webpack_require__ (index.js:67)
    (anonyme Funktion) (index.js:93:94)
    (anonyme Funktion) (index.js:95)
    Globaler Code (index.js:96)
```

I don't know if I missed something, or if this is all completely wrong but to my understanding it should work.

Comment: Problem is solved in: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77354217/why-do-i-get-a-typeerror-when-importing-wordpress-element)
I forgot to add the dependencies in the .php