# Why do I get a TypeError when importing @wordpress/element

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, wordpress, react-dom

Same problem as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77353239/typeerror-when-importing-createroot-from-react-dom-client).

But now I'm importing `'@wordpress/element'` instead of `'react-dom/client'` because I've read that you can also use this, as it builds on react.

Now I get a different Error in the console when I write this:
`import { createRoot } from '@wordpress/element';`

Error:

```
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window["wp"]["element"]')
    @wordpress/element (index.js:21)
    __webpack_require__ (index.js:45)
    (anonyme Funktion) (index.js:102:96)
    (anonyme Funktion) (index.js:109)
    Globaler Code (index.js:110)
```

I think this problem is occurring in this file:
`module.exports = window["wp"]["element"];`

which is created automatically.

My goal is just to import `createRoot` from  `react-dom` and I don't know why it won't work.

(But again I'm a beginner and maybe thinking completely wrong)

Comment: Can you share some details on how you're building your app? Gutenberg itself uses wp-scripts, which has a webpack config that declares `@wordpress/element` as external on `window.wp.element` if you have your own build script, you may have to do this also depending on your circumstances

Comment: @Andrew the error mentioned occurred when I ran wp-script start, when I use wp-script build I get another error
`[Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.wp.element')`

Comment: I imagine your script is loading too early. when using `wp_enqueue_script` you need to make sure that `wp-element`, and any other dependencies,  are listed in the script dependency array. wp-scripts should also output a php file that includes the dependencies,  check for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you need to do is import the index.asset.php, and pass its dependencies into your script dependency array:

```php
function my_enq_scripts(){
   $inc = require 'build/index.asset.php';
   wp_enqueue_script('my-script-name', '/build/index.js', $inc['dependencies'], $inc['version']);
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','my_enq_scripts');
```

you can also make a more development-friendly version like:

```php
$version = defined( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG' ) && SCRIPT_DEBUG ? time() : $inc['version'];
wp_enqueue_script('my-script-name', '/build/index.js', $inc['dependencies'], $version);
```